# Three.js How to find World orientation vector of object's local Up vector?

Tags: vector, three.js, rotation

My object3D has an up vector (0,1,0).  The object3D moves its origin around yawing, pitching and rolling.

My Question:
How do I find the vector which shows the direction of the object3D's up vector in world coordinates?

Example of coding context:-

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3();

v1.add( givenObject3D.up ); // now v1 = (0,1,0)

givenObject3D.updateMatrixWorld();

FunctionXXX (v1, givenObject3D.matrixWorld  ); 

//... now v1 is a vector in world coordinates 
//... v1 points in the same direction as the givenObject3D's up vector.

v1.normalize();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to get the world orientation of an object's `up` vector. To do so, apply the same rotation to the `up` vector that is applied to the object.

If the object is a child of the scene directly, then you can do this:

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse it
...
v1.copy( object.up ).applyQuaternion( object.quaternion );
```

If the object has a rotated parent, then you need to use this pattern:

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse it
var worldQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(); // create once and reuse it
...
object.getWorldQuaternion( worldQuaternion );
v1.copy( object.up ).applyQuaternion( worldQuaternion );
```

three.js r.74