# Aligning 3D position and orientation of a HTML div with an animated Three.js plane Object3D

Tags: matrix, three.js, quaternions

Trying to align HTML content over a Threejs background where I need to match a div with a 3d plane.

Following [this post](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-align-html-elements-to-3d.html) I was able to get the div to follow the plane position, but i m still having trouble with the orientation even following advices from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641875/three-js-how-to-find-world-orientation-vector-of-objects-local-up-vector)

So far this is my code:

```
screenPlane.updateWorldMatrix()
screenPlane.getWorldPosition(tempV)
screenPlane.getWorldQuaternion(tempQuat)
tempRotationV3.copy(screenPlane.up ).applyQuaternion(tempQuat)
tempV.project(camera)
const x = (tempV.x *  .5 + .5) * container.clientWidth
const y = (tempV.y * -.5 + .5) * container.clientHeight
div.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x}px,${y}px) `
div.style.transform += ` rotateX(${tempRotationV3.x}rad) rotateY(-${tempRotationV3.y}rad) rotateZ(${tempRotationV3.z}rad)`
```

Position is good but orientation is clearly broken:

[image]

[Here is a jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mikatalk/ec7d498w/) of the position only

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into using CSS3DRenderer? https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS3DRenderer there are a few demos in that page.

Comment: For some reason i was convinced it was deprecated from Three, i ll look into it, definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Marquizzo comment i was able to [fix the fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mikatalk/gpyxa5k7/) using `CSS3DRenderer`

```
var div = document.getElementById('overlay');
var cssScene = new THREE.Scene();
var cssObject = new CSS3DObject(div);
// we reference the same position and rotation 
cssObject.position.set(plane.position.x, plane.position.y, plane.position.z);
cssObject.rotation.set(plane.rotation.x, plane.rotation.y, plane.rotation.z);
// add it to the css scene
cssScene.add(cssObject);

var cssRenderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
cssRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
cssRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
cssRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
document.body.appendChild( cssRenderer.domElement );
window.div = cssObject
```

Note that `CSS3DRenderer` is not deprecated by ThreeJS but it is shipped separately in order to keep the main library lighter. So make sure you import it separately:

```
import { CSS3DRenderer, CSS3DObject } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js';
```